# Confusion about "Proofreader" Badge

Tags: support, badges

"Proofreader" Badge awarded to approved or rejected 100 suggested edits but if you see my suggestions count it is [109](https://stackoverflow.com/users/718224/advait-amin?tab=activity). So my question is why I am not getting badge of "proofreader" or there is something else required for that?

Comment: That badge is for **reviewing** suggested edits, not suggesting them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The badge is awarded to the reviewer not to the one who is suggesting.

Comment: explain briefly.

Comment: @AdvaitAmin - As animuson already commented: The badge is for **reviewing** suggested edit not for *suggesting* the edit. You can earn this badge if you **review** 100 suggested edit. You have suggested 100+ edits not reviewed it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1426687 in that link i have 97 edit suggestions approved that count you saying.

Comment: @AdvaitAmin you need to either **approve** or **reject** edits suggested by other users; that's what reviewing means.

Comment: That does not count, Advait. You are not eligible for the Proofreader badge. You won't be eligible until you have 2000 reputation, and are therefore [able to approve the suggested edits that other users make](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit). Right now, you can *suggest* edits. Other users, those with at least 2000 reputation, must *approve* the edits that you make. The Proofreader badge is awarded to those users that approve edits.

Comment: @Advait No, it's not what he's saying. The badge goes to those 2k users who actually go through the review queue and decide to approve or reject suggested edits. So, if you suggest an edit and hims056 looks at it and says "that looks good, I'll approve it), then it counts for hims056 getting the badge, not you.
Note that you can't get the badge until you have over 2k, because you can't review edits until then.

Comment: So how can i approved or reject suggested by other users after 2000 reputation?

Comment: @AdvaitAmin - From here: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits

Comment: Once you have 2000 reputation, you'll see a link at the top of the page named **review**, Advait.

Comment: OK get it thank you Michael Petrotta, Sha Wiz Dow Ard, cpast & hims056.